# Getting number of columns in a table using ' Proc C-C``

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

I am using the below code to get the number of columns in an oracle table.

```
char selectQuery[30000] = {'\0'};
strcpy(selectQuery, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=\'");
strcat(selectQuery, tableName);
strcat(selectQuery, "\'");

strcpy((char*) stmt.arr, selectQuery);
stmt.len = strlen((char*) stmt.arr );
stmt.arr[stmt.len]= '\0';

EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE;
EXEC SQL WHENEVER NOT FOUND CONTINUE;

EXEC SQL DECLARE SELECTCOLNU STATEMENT;
EXEC SQL PREPARE SELECTCOLNU FROM :stmt;

if(sqlca.sqlcode != 0)
{
    DEBUG_LOG("SQL-ERR:Preparation of SELECT Query to get number of columns failed: Ora-Err: %d %s\n", sqlca.sqlcode, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
    return PREPARATION_FAILURE;
}

EXEC SQL EXECUTE SELECTCOLNU INTO:columnsNo;
if(sqlca.sqlcode < 0)
{
    DEBUG_LOG("SQL-ERR:Execute failed: Ora-Err: %d %s\n", sqlca.sqlcode, sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc);
    return EXECTUION_FAILURE;
}

DEBUG_LOG("Number of columns: %d\n", columnsNo);
```

When I execute the code, It doesn't give any error but I am getting "Number of columns: 0" as the output.
There are few columns in the table I am referring.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Below is the declaration section...

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    int columnsNo;
    VARCHAR stmt[MAX_SQL];
EXEC SQL END DECLARE SECTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't "escape" the `'` in a C- string. It will have `\'` just in the string, and that is not what you want because the `'` is the database string quote, which you now escape *for the database* and the database doesn't understand the query now.

```
sprintf(selectQuery, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='%s'", tableName);
```

---

Note:

```
stmt.len = strlen((char*) stmt.arr );
stmt.arr[stmt.len]= '\0';
```

In the above `strlen` counts the number of characters until a null character. Thus `stmt.arr[stmt.len]` is already null. (No harm, though.)

Comment: I used the "sprintf" to prepare the query, It was executed successfully. But still I am getting 0 for number of columns.

Comment: Sory, I don't "speak" embedded SQL. But I notice you tell SQL to ignore errors. You may now not get the error/warnings that could help you.

Comment: I was getting an error because of "if (sqlca.sqlcode == 1403) break;" without a loop. Hence I ignored the errors.

Comment: That is C warning, not an ORA warning. I refer to `WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE`

Comment: I used cursor to fetch the column count. Now its working. Thanks for your reply.